# Error 'GDAL extension not installed' while installing cartaro

Tags: geoserver, gdal, tomcat, boundless-suite

I am trying to install Cartaro on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have followed every step from this guide: http://cartaro.org/documentation/installation

But on the 'Verify Requirements' page I get this warning which says ''GDAL extension not installed'. Also when I click on proceed with installation, on Setup database page I see mysql and SQLite as options type not PostgreSQL as shown [here](http://drupal.org/files/database-configuration.png)

Here is what I did:

After using

```
sudo unzip geoserver-2.3.5-war.zip geoserver.war -d /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/
```

I opened /etc/default/tomcat7 and added the following code in the end

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DENABLE_JSONP=true"
```

Then I edited geoserver/WEB-INF/web.xml and added the following code just after web-app starting tag.

```
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>33333</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

Please tell me what did I do wrong and what is the correct way to install the GDAL extension.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The page [Building and installing the PHP GDAL extension](https://drupal.org/node/2133103) in the Drupal Community Documentation is helpful.

The main part being to download and install from source, [php5-gdal from its github repository](https://github.com/geops/php5-gdal). Some development tools may need to be installed before-hand.

```
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Then configure and enable the module.

```
sudo echo -e "; configuration for the PHP GDAL extension\nextension=gdal.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/gdal.ini
sudo php5enmod gdal
```

Followed by restarting the apache web service. For example:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

---

Tested on Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with this command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```

you can also install more

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal python-gdal gdal-bin
```

or even more, just to make sure that you have everything:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-gdal python-gdal gdal-bin libgdal-dev libgdal1-dev  libgdal1h
```

Comment: I tried to install GDAL via the first link, still same problem. I don't know what to do in second link.